# How to search Internet Archive for all pages from a particular domain

Tags: archive.org

I'd like to find all pages, files, etc. that are archived at the Internet Archive (archive.org) from a particular domain (ex. everything from abcd.com) .  Entering the url into the WayBack Machine isn't good enough because that only gives me access to files linked on that page.

Answer (score 15):

I think I found a way:

1. Search for the domain, such as `domain.com`
2. If there are any results, click on `Summary of [domain]`
3. Scroll down to the link saying `Explore [domain] URLs`
4. Then you'll get a list of every URL found at that domain with a count for unique and duplicate results.

Comment: Nice, this works too.

Comment: You have to wait for a while, the site is under heavy load, and so it is very slow...

Answer (score 9):

Goto **archive.org**. Use the asterisk:

[image]

Wait for it to load when it says [searching](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcMMv.png).

---

(Works only for the **top** search box.)

(**web.archive.org** will not show the top search box. (Go **archive.org**))

(The other search boxes have weird usability bugs; but it always work if you visit the link **web.archive.org/web/*/example.org/*** directly.)

Comment: `web.archive.org/web/*/example.org/*` seems to be the easiest and most reliable of all the solutions here.

Answer (score 1):

A quick test indicates it uses the same syntax as [Google](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2466433?hl=en):
`test site:microsoft.com`

**Update 2023**

Things have changed in the last 6 years, but this still works *if you are searching the Wayback Machine*:
[image]

This search behaves differently and doesn't work:
[image]